# Possible to merge PC and Pocket Edition Minecraft servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

How feasible would it be to run a Bukkit/Spigot/whatever server and sync it with a PocketMine server?  Ideally, players would be able to interact (see and chat) with each other even if they're on different servers, and the world map would sync as well, so structures and terrain would be the same and update when changes are made.

I know this would require custom plugins.  Assume the servers are either on the same machine or the machines have a high-speed connection to each other.
I want to know if there are any technical issues with doing this type of setup.

The only big problem I can think of is differences in available items, but that can be worked around by only allowing items/blocks present in both versions of the game.

Comment: Pocket edition and the full version of Minecraft are made in two entirely different programming languages (Java and C++ I think). Allowing them to connect would be nearly impossible, even if you were to solve the item difference issues.

Comment: Don't see anything too impossible about it, but it would need a lot of effort to make work, and interacting with players on the other version may be a bit buggy.

Comment: @angussidney I'm talking about server plugins.  There are protocols designed to allow cross-platform communication, and PocketMine is PHP anyways.

Comment: I dont think its possible, because, there are blocks/items in both versions, which dont exist in the other. Syncing them would require modded clients for both platforms.

Comment: @Mystery Inventories can be limited to only items that exist in both, see my question.

Comment: But there are other limitations(worldsize for example) which would have to be applied to the server as well. I think its easier to write a PC client for PE servers than writing a server, which can deal with both client types.

Comment: This is very possible and I know there is a server software project which aims to support different MC versions and editions and provide an API for developers. I cannot remember the name nor can I remember the progress so far. Might report back later. I ain't saying this is a good solution and will have many players and server owners use it.

Comment: @angussidney Programs being written in different languages, doesn't mean it's impossible to communicate. They just need to speak the same protocol over network.

Answer (score 1):

For Minecraft pe servers there is a plugin "big brother"(https://github.com/shoghicp/BigBrother/releases) which allows pc to join the pe server and play with pe players. But it's outdated. There is also updated server software called redstone lamp which you can join from bother pe and pc(https://github.com/RedstoneLamp).

Edit: Bukkit can't do that.

Comment: The github link is no longer valid. Redstonelamp.net is a parking site, Your best bet may be https://github.com/Asparanc/RedstoneLamp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like someone did it: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVmx8dmobyU)

In case, the video goes down:
Its a plugin for [PocketMine](http://forums.pocketmine.net/threads/pocketmine-mp-alpha_1-4dev-is-available-for-testing.3660/), called BigBrother.
This plugin allows you to join a PE server using the PC version of Minecraft.
The plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/shoghicp/BigBrother/releases).